# SQL Server displaying data when its available

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am considering four sites to track orders in a week  site1, site2, site3 and site 4, 
if there is no orderdate against those sites in the last week then i am getting a count of 0 
as expected

here is a query,

```
select  SiteName
    ,SUM(Case When  DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) > DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()), getdate()))
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as Orders
from SiteOrder where SiteName in ('Site1','Site2','Site3','Site4')
GROUP BY SiteName
order by SiteName
```

all well and good so far,
there are other three sites that i need to consider in future as and when there records start appearing, i could just include those sites in where clause like

```
 ('Site1','Site2','Site3','Site4','Site5','Site6','Site7')
```

but that will start giving me 0 against those sites if there is no orderdate which i dont want.
so lets say site 4 is expected in three weeks and there is a orderdate entered after three weeks, i want to start showing that site count and in subsequent weeks if there is no orderdate than by all means show 0, maybe its magic and not possible, but i thought ill check with the world before i give up

Comment: So you want to start seeing a new siteX after the first order date for that site and then see it forever thereafter?

Comment: pretty much so, but only three new sites

Comment: What is your intention with: DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) > DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()), getdate())) It looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: Right, that is "in the last week" part. I missed that when I read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment I'm not clear on what the intention with your date math is, but if you flip it around in a HAVING clause you can restrict the result to Site that have past orders.

```
SELECT SiteName
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN  DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) > DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS Orders
  FROM SiteOrder 
 WHERE SiteName IN ('Site1','Site2','Site3','Site4','Site5','Site6','Site7')
 GROUP BY SiteName
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) <= DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(DAY, -6 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
           END) > 1
 ORDER BY SiteName
```

I think there is a more efficient way to do it, but I want to make we understand what we are trying to accomplish before worrying about that.

Comment: DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) > DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()), getdate()))    only gives records for last week

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that in the question. I'll revise.

Comment: So if we adjust the having to look for orders more than a week old, does that do it?

Comment: Karl, i dont have access to the system right now, will check tomorrow thanks a lot